# Merge rows based on values and key string in awk, sed or python

Tags: python, bash, sed, awk

I have the following input table:

```
  1 2   A   "aaa"
  3 4   A   "aaa"
  5 6   A   "aaa"
  1 2   B   "bbb"
  3 4   B   "bbb"
  1 2   A   "ccc"
```

I'd like to get:

output1 - from input print lowest and highest values from column 1 and column 2, respectively, with the same name in column 4

```
  1 6   A   "aaa"
  1 4   B   "bbb"
  1 2   A   "ccc"
```

output2 - from input print values in column 1 and 2 'between the rows'; take values from column 2 (row 1) and column 1 (row 2) into a new row 1 with the same name in column 4 (skip when name in column 4 changes, like in rows 3, 5, 6 of the input).

```
  2 3   A   "aaa"
  4 5   A   "aaa"
  2 3   B   "bbb"
```

I'd really appreciate your advice.

Thanks in advance!

Comment: So many of could have answers this question but due to lack of effort shown by OP there is no answer here.

Comment: Sorry for that, I'm just a beginner, I've tried to solve is with some single liners in awk, with no real progress :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

In python you can try the following solution. I edited it to make it accept not only consecutive numbers for indices.

```
# -*- encoding: utf-8 -*-

def get_min_max_index(data):
    result = dict()
    names = set([record[3] for record in data])
    for name in names:
    name_records = filter(lambda record: record[3] == name, data)
    name_indices = map(lambda record: (record[0], record[1]), name_records)
    record_id = name_records[0][2]
    result[name] = (min(name_indices)[0], max(name_indices)[1], record_id, name_indices)
    return result

def get_between_rows(data):
    records_min_max = get_min_max_index(data)
    result = list()
    for i in range(len(data) - 1):
    name = data[i][3]
    max_ind = records_min_max[name][1]
    if data[i][1] < max_ind:
        result.append([data[i][1], data[i+1][0], data[i][2], data[i][3]])
    return result

if __name__ == "__main__":
    import sys
    data = list()
    for line in sys.stdin.readlines():
    line = line.strip().split()
    data.append([int(line[0]), int(line[1]), line[2], line[3].strip('"')])
    for name, line in get_min_max_index(data).items():
    print('{0} {1} {2} {3}'.format(line[0], line[1], line[2], name))
    print('\n')
    for line in get_between_rows(data):
    print('{0} {1} {2} {3}'.format(line[0], line[1], line[2], line[3]))


# vim:expandtab:smartindent:tabstop=4:softtabstop=4:shiftwidth=4:
```

Here is the result of the command `cat linked.txt | python linked.py`

```
1 6 A aaa
1 4 B bbb
1 2 A ccc


2 3 A aaa
4 5 A aaa
2 3 B bbb
```

Comment: Many thanks and sorry, looks like I oversimplified the example, in the real data the numbers are usually not consecutive, but they always increase for a given name in column 4 (specified between apostrophe)

Comment: Please see my update answer. I suppose you could do it yourself with little efforts :)

Comment: one more question; if the table has more columns which I simply want to print as they are (let's say two more column before the numbers), what's the best way to do this; I don't quite get your solution with the record_id in line 9 :)
result[name] = (record [0], record [1], min(name_indices)[0], max(name_indices)[1], record_id, name_indices) ?

Comment: The list name_indices contains the first two values of you line for given row, specified by it `name`. I call `name` the strings on the end of the lines like `aaa`, `bbb` etc. For instance, for the first line `name_indices` will be `(1, 2)`. If you want some more columns in the beginning (let say 2 new columns) this will shift everything related to `record` to the right. For example,  you will have `(record[2], record[3])` on the line starting with `name_indices =` instead of `(record[0], record[1])`

Comment: Because you have no `line` defined there :)

Comment: sorry I meant record not line (deleted) :) I simply want to print what's in the rest of the columns (like in col 3 in the example), and I'm not sure why you use record_id for this:)

Comment: You have no `record` too in the context of the `get_min_max` method. You have it only inside the internal loops of the functions `map()` and `filter()`. If your additional 2 columns are identical for all lines with the same `name` you can access them as `name_records[0][0]` and `name_records[0][1]`. The same I do for `record_id`

Comment: got it all now, seem to work well; but it's very slow; for a 500k-row table (with 10 columns) it takes about half an hour :)

Answer (score 2):

Here is one way to do part #1 with `awk`

```
awk '!b[$3" "$4]||b[$3" "$4]>$1 {b[$3" "$4]=$1} !t[$3" "$4]||b[$3" "$4]<$2 {t[$3" "$4]=$2} END {for (i in b) print b[i],t[i],i}' file
1 2 A "ccc"
1 6 A "aaa"
1 4 B "bbb"
```

---

If column #3 is always connected to column #4

```
awk '!b[$4]||b[$4]>$1 {b[$4]=$1} !t[$4]||b[$4]<$2 {t[$4]=$2} {z[$4]=$3} END {for (i in b) print b[i],t[i],z[i],i}' file
1 6 A "aaa"
1 2 A "ccc"
1 4 B "bbb"
```

Comment: Thanks for your answer, it does the thing, but considering both columns $3 and $4, and I'd like it to consider only what's between  apostrophe in $4, i.e. aaa or bbb

Comment: What to do with column `#3` if its changing and its not the same as `#4`, what to print then, the first hit, last?  Se my updated my post with no column #3

Comment: awk '!b[$4]||b[$4]>$1 {b[$4]=$1} !t[$4]||b[$4]<$2 {t[$4]=$2} !z[$4]||b[$4]>$1 {z[$4]=$3} END {for (i in b) print b[i],t[i],z[i],i}' file

Comment: It will work, but only if field #3 and #4 connected with same information.

Comment: thanks, now it does the job, do you know how specify the name, not instead the column 4; in case there is multiple values in column 4, I'd like to consider one in apostrophe

Comment: Not sure what you mean, can you give an example.  PS I have updated my post with column #3.  No need to test it, since its always connected to column #4

Comment: 1 2 A "aaa";aaa;bbb;333
for this example it should only consider the first aaa, as specified by "", the rest of column 4 can be different

Comment: What will you do with the rest of the line? Delete it, store first found, last found etc,

Comment: store everything, but use only what's in "" to merge columns 1 and 2

Comment: So if first line is `1 2   A   "aaa"some text` and second is `2 3   A   "aaa"my data` you like to output to be. `1 3   A   "aaa"some text my data`??

Comment: the dataset is already quite large, so it would be better to store the first found as you've suggested